# Copied a local cake website on new machine and getting dispatch(new CakeRequest() message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have copied a cake project over to a new pc set it up exactly the same as the other machine, but I am getting the following message:

```
dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Is that the whole message? It looks like that's just a part of a stack trace. Try viewing the source and paste the entire stack trace here.

Comment: You know what a stack trace is? This is not a stack trace. That's the code of index.php. Copy the exact and complete error message and add it to the question.

Comment: @burzum I have turned debug level to 3, but I am not getting an error messages at all

Comment: Define how you get this "message"? Is it showing that single line of code in the browser or what?

Comment: Also try looking in your web server's error log as well as `app/tmp/logs/error.log` and `app/tmp/logs/debug.log` for further pointers what might be wrong.

Comment: @burzum, it was just ebing outputted on the screen, when i viewed source I could see loads of php,which indicates PHP is not running, I fugured it was a xampp issue, I reinstalled xampp and it works now